# Using OR Condition in JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm fetching records by doing some multiple Joins. I need to add one more with OR condition.

There is a table `Payment`. From `Payment` have to join with:

- table Package1(if Payment.PaymentTypeID=1)  OR with
- table Package2(if Payment.PaymentTypeID=3).

Both the tables Package1 and Package2 have a column VoucherID and have to be fetched based on the above condition. I can do it by below query using Union or Union All, but please let me know if I can do it without using UNion or Union All.

```
select  P1.VoucherID  from Payment P
inner join Package1 P1 on P1.empid=P.empid and P.PaymentTypeID=1

union all

select  P2.VoucherID  from Payment P
inner join Package1 P2 on P2.empid=P.empid and P.PaymentTypeID=3
```

Comment: Use the `UNION ALL`. Why don't you want to?

Comment: Should the statement after union all be joining on Package2? Is Package1 a typo?

Answer (score 2):

You can put an `or` in the `on` condition:

```
select P1.VoucherID
from Payment P inner join
     Package1 P1
     on (P1.empid=P.empid and P.PaymentTypeID=1) or
        (P1.empid=P.empid and P.PaymentTypeID=3);
```

This, in turn, can be written as:

```
select P1.VoucherID
from Payment P inner join
     Package1 P1
     on (P1.empid=P.empid and P.PaymentTypeID in (1, 3);
```

It is quite possible that the `union` version will perform better.  `or` in the join condition often makes it harder to optimize a query.

EDIT:

If you have two tables, then a `left outer join` might work:

```
select coalesce(P1.VoucherID, P2.VoucherId) as VoucherId
from Payment P left outer join
     Package1 P1
     on (P1.empid = P1.empid and P.PaymentTypeID=1) left outer join
     Package2 P2
     on (P1.empid = P2.empid and P.PaymentTypeID=3)
where P1.VoucherId is not null or P2.VoucherId is not null;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I need to match with two different tables Package1 and Package2 for Payment.PaymentTypeID=1 and Payment.PaymentTypeID=3 respectively.

Comment: @user1429135 . . . Your sample code in the question uses only one table.

Comment: It should actually work like: select  P1.VoucherID  from Payment P
inner join Package1 P1 on P1.empid=P.empid and P.PaymentTypeID=1

union all

select  P2.VoucherID  from Payment P
inner join Package1 P2 on P2.empid=P.empid and P.PaymentTypeID=3

Comment: @user1429135 . . . Your comment continues to only refer to `Package1` and not `Package2`.  In any case, the answer has been edited for both situations.

Comment: I'm getting the desired result by using coalesce and left outer join. But, there are null values also. Can we eliminate those null values. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: @user1429135 . . . Of course.  The NULLs come when neither of the conditions are met.  It is a simple matter to require at least one match in the `where` clause (which I just edited).

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
select 
   P1.VoucherID 
from 
   Payment P 
inner join Package1 P1 
   on P1.empid=P.empid 
   and P.PaymentTypeID IN (1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd retreive vouchers from both tables Package1 and 2 and then decide what to select depending on PaymentTypeId's value using the IF() function.

```
select  IF(P.PaymentTypeID=1, P1.VoucherID, P2.VoucherID) as VoucherId from Payment P
inner join Package2 P2 on P2.empid=P.empid
inner join Package1 P1 on P1.empid=P.empid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do them in 1 select statment and then use `COALESCE` to extract the first non-null value.

```
SELECT
     COALESCE(P1.VoucherID, P2.VoucherID) as VoucherID
FROM 
    Payment P
INNER JOIN
    Package1 P1 
ON
    P1.empid = P.empid AND P.PaymentTypeID = 1
INNER JOIN
    Package2 P2 
ON 
    P2.empid = P.empid AND P.PaymentTypeID = 3
```